# environment variable uncontrolled update

Tags: environment-variables, cypress

I'm currently trying to handle cy.request headers in a dynamic way.

To do this I set a default header in an environment variable and, if required for a particular request, I append additional headers.

The problem is that by the end of the request, the environment variable is updated automatically with the local header value.

Here is the code I use :

```
function my_function(jSessionCookie) {
    // build header
    let header = Cypress.env("defaultAPIheader")
    console.log("default header = ", header) // (1)
    header["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
    header["Cookie"] = jSessionCookie
    console.log("header = ", header) // (2)
    return cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: header,
        url: '<my_url>',
        body: null,
        referer: '/rootapp/index.html',
        referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        failOnStatusCode: true
    }).its('body').then((body) => {
        Cypress.env("requestToken", body) // store for further use
        console.log("default header2 = ", Cypress.env("defaultAPIheader")) // (3)
        return body
    })
}
```

What I can see from the console is :

```
(1) default header =  {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'}
(2) header = {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Connection: 'keep-alive', Cookie: '<my_cookie>'} which is what I expect
(3) default header2 = {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Connection: 'keep-alive', Cookie: '<my_cookie>'}
```

It looks like environment variable has been replaced by local value but it can't figure out how it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collegue found out what was the problem (thank you Robin !). The variable setting was giving a reference instead of the value.
In order to avoid that I modified my code as follows :

```
let header = Cypress._.cloneDeep(Cypress.env("defaultAPIheader"))
```

by setting `const { _, $ } = Cypress` at the beginning of the file, it can be reduced :

```
let header = _.cloneDeep(Cypress.env("defaultAPIheader"))
```

This no longer modifies my environment variable.